# Is it possible to make get variable out of filter in Class?

Tags: filters, actions, oop

I am trying to have a variable out of the filter

At the end of there is `return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', $items, $endpoints );`

```
function wc_get_account_menu_items() {
    $endpoints = array(
        'orders'          => get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_orders_endpoint', 'orders' ),
        'downloads'       => get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_downloads_endpoint', 'downloads' ),
        'edit-address'    => get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_edit_address_endpoint', 'edit-address' ),
        'payment-methods' => get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_payment_methods_endpoint', 'payment-methods' ),
        'edit-account'    => get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_edit_account_endpoint', 'edit-account' ),
        'customer-logout' => get_option( 'woocommerce_logout_endpoint', 'customer-logout' ),
    );

    $items = array(
        'dashboard'       => __( 'Dashboard', 'woocommerce' ),
        'orders'          => __( 'Orders', 'woocommerce' ),
        'downloads'       => __( 'Downloads', 'woocommerce' ),
        'edit-address'    => _n( 'Addresses', 'Address', (int) wc_shipping_enabled(), 'woocommerce' ),
        'payment-methods' => __( 'Payment methods', 'woocommerce' ),
        'edit-account'    => __( 'Account details', 'woocommerce' ),
        'customer-logout' => __( 'Logout', 'woocommerce' ),
    );

    // Remove missing endpoints.
    foreach ( $endpoints as $endpoint_id => $endpoint ) {
        if ( empty( $endpoint ) ) {
            unset( $items[ $endpoint_id ] );
        }
    }

    // Check if payment gateways support add new payment methods.
    if ( isset( $items['payment-methods'] ) ) {
        $support_payment_methods = false;
        foreach ( WC()->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways() as $gateway ) {
            if ( $gateway->supports( 'add_payment_method' ) || $gateway->supports( 'tokenization' ) ) {
                $support_payment_methods = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( ! $support_payment_methods ) {
            unset( $items['payment-methods'] );
        }
    }

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', $items, $endpoints );
}
```

if I have a class like this

```
Class MyClass{
   public function __construct(){
          add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', array($this, 'wooquickmy_grab_endpoints'), 10 , 1 );
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this,'wooquickmy_options_page' ));
  }

   public function wooquickmy_options_page(){
         //get the return value from there wooquickmy_grab_endpoints
    }

public function wooquickmy_grab_endpoints($endpoints){
        return $endpoints ;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get that return value inside the action that I have created?
What is the best possible option for such cases?

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: `admin_menu` runs in the back end, and `woocommerce_account_menu_items` runs on the front end, so no, you won't be able to get the list of endpoints in the back-end.

Answer (score -1):

The filter has 2 args, not one.

Try:

```
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', array($this, 'wooquickmy_grab_endpoints'), 10 , 2 );

public function wooquickmy_grab_endpoints($items, $endpoints){
        // do something with $endpoints
        return $items;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but the question is not that, I need: `wooquickmy_options_page` function to have the return value in  `wooquickmy_grab_endpoints `

Comment: Then set a class variable to the value of `$endpoints`. But `admin_menu` probably fires _before_ the filter hook - if so, the value will not be available.